# CATAN- May one player build roads that pass perpendicularly through another player's established roads?

Tags: catan

If player one has built a road system through intersection A. Is it within the rules for player B to build a road system that passes through intersection A from the perpendicular direction? Or is that illegal since player A has already built roads passing through that intersection?

Comment: This question, as asked, doesn't make sense.  Catan is played on a hex grid, so there are only three valid road spots on each intersection, and it is therefore not possible for two players to build roads "through" the same intersection.  Please include a diagram of the situation you are envisioning or clarify the question.

Answer (score 5):

What you say is not possible, as there are only 3 different ways that a road could go into an intersection (and in some places just 2, so perpendicularity is not possible). However, it is technically legal for someone to build a road into an intersection where another player already has two roads going through. (Other than the purpose of blocking a player's route however, this is not usually a beneficial move for the player taking it.) In the below example, the green player could make a road going into the red player's intersection legally. (Sorry for the green, I know its not a Catan color, but it was the only color arrow I had.)

[image: Example 1]

It is also legal for a player to insert two roads, effectively blocking another player's route into an intersection in which he has only one road. In Example 2 (below), the green player built two roads to cut off the red's road at the water-ore-desert hex.

[image: Example 2]

Comment: You get green in the 5/6 player expansion.

Comment: It can be very advantageous for a second player to build to that intersection if that intersection is still a valid settlement spot.  In your first example, if green builds a settlement on the shared intersection, not only will green then have a settlement there, it will also break red's road into two roads for the purposes of longest road